# Application delegates are not calling while application entered into background

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, uiapplicationdelegate

I am implementing an iPhone application.I am downloading data from server by using asynchronous request in the application.If, I Press the home button, My application delegate is not calling directly.After completion of data downloading from server, application delegate methods are calling.So, How can i get the immediate Delegate call in my application.

Any help can be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Which delegate methods are you implementing? Can you post what you've tried (code-wise) here? Note that once your application has been moved to the background, **you can only run short-term tasks** to preserve battery life.

This example is provided by Apple:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIApplication*    app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you.
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```

If you want to perform longer running tasks, you require special permissions, and even then can only perform a certain subset of actions. They are discussed here:

[**iOS App Programming Guide: App States and Multitasking**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20)